# Getting error when trying to migrate in django

Tags: python, django

Hey I'm trying to migrate my project using the command `python manage.py makemigrations` in django and I keep getting this error:

```
  File "manage.py", line 14
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have already found similar answers on it but nothing has worked. I am currently in the virtual environment already and changing the command to `python3 manage.py makemigrations` also prompts the same error.

Comment: It will be useful to post all the traceback, we can't help with what you post

Comment: Paste more code around where this error is referring to.  Paste more of the stacktrace that prints this error.

Comment: Did you use an old Python version?

Comment: Note if you use a virtual environment to run your project. make sure it is active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `raise-from` statement, or [exception chaining](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/), is only supported since Python 3.

Please upgrade your Python version to 3.0 or above in order to run this [manage.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/project_template/manage.py-tpl).

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you do find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)